# Why doesn't S.notice show up after redirect in lift mvc v2.3

Tags: session, redirect, lift

when requesting:

case "page" :: AsInt(id) :: Nil => {
        S.notice("Hello world!")
        S.redirectTo("/index")
    }

redirects to:

case "index" :: Nil => {
      // replace the contents of the element with id "time" with the date
      "#time *" #> DependencyFactory.inject[Date].map(_.toString)
    }

however "Hello world!" doesn't show up. It will show up on page if I comment the redirectTo.

Can anyone tell me why the session isn't persisting past the redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that's because *S.notice()* places message in request scope and it's not available after redirect (new request is created).

See following quotes from [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net/) book:

> The `net.liftweb.http.S` object represents the state of the current request.
>
> The messages that you send are held by a `RequestVar` in the `S` object.

But:

> You can also send Lift messages (notices, warnings, and errors) that
>   will be rendered in the redirected page, as well as cookies to be set on redirect. Similarly, there is an overloaded version of `S.redirectTo` that allows you to specify a function to be executed when the redirect is processed.

So I think you can use following version of *redirectTo* method for this purpose:

`def redirectTo [T] (where: String, func: () ⇒ Unit) : T`

and make *S.notice* call inside registered function (second parameter).

Best Regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
S.redirectTo("/index", () => S.notice("Hello World!"))
```